# how to select top 5 products from table

Tags: java, mysql

```
+-------+-----+-------+----------+-------+
| iniid | iID | price | quentity | proID |
+-------+-----+-------+----------+-------+
|    42 |  16 |    20 |       30 |  4001 |
|    43 |  16 |    20 |       30 |  4001 |
|    44 |  16 |    20 |       30 |  4002 |
|    45 |  16 |    20 |       30 |  4002 |
|    46 |  17 |    20 |        1 |  4001 |
|    47 |  17 |    20 |        1 |  4003 |
|    48 |  17 |    20 |        1 |  4005 |
|    49 |  17 |    20 |        1 |  4001 |
|    50 |  17 |    20 |        1 |  4009 |
|    51 |  17 |    20 |        1 |  4002 |
|    52 |  17 |    20 |        1 |  4001 |
|    53 |  17 |    20 |        1 |  4005 |
|    54 |  17 |    20 |        1 |  4008 |
|    55 |  17 |    20 |        1 |  4008|
|    56 |  17 |    20 |        1 |  4007 |
|    57 |  17 |    20 |        1 |  4000 |
|    58 |  18 |    20 |        2 |  4005 |
|    59 |  18 |    20 |        2 |  4002 |
|    60 |  18 |    20 |        2 |  4003 |
|    61 |  18 |    20 |        2 |  4003 |
|    62 |  18 |    20 |        2 |  4009 |
|    63 |  18 |    20 |        2 |  4003 |
|    64 |  18 |    20 |        2 |  4002 |
```

now i want to find top 5 selling products of a specific month .i have invoice registry too,so i can get `'iId'` for specific month .my question is how can i select top 5 products for given iId.proID can be same or different[normally different] .top means maximum quantity.so i want product id(proID) of top 5 [quantity] .i tried to write mysql query but failed.

```
select (top 5 quentity) from invoice where iID>15;

expected result

total quentity of 4001=63;
total quentity of 4002=65;
........and so on.........

so top 2 products are 4002 and 4001;
so i wanna get 4002,4001,.....[5th product]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL uses `LIMIT` instead of `TOP`.  Just order your `quentity` field `DESC` and you'll get the top 5 records with the highest `quentity`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Invoice
WHERE iID>15
ORDER BY quentity DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Note, it's possible you're fifth result would be a tie. If you need to account for ties, you can use user defined variables.

---

Given your edits, you want to `SUM` the `quentity` field, and then order the results be the highest summed quantities.

```
SELECT proId, SUM(quentity)
FROM Invoice
WHERE iID > 15
GROUP BY proId
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: @sgedded the problem is i want to find top 5 products those have highest quantity.proID is product id .according to ur answer this will give me all highest quantities.

Comment: @PiumiWandana -- Given your edits, I've edited my reply.  Sounds like you're looking for `SUM`.